# How to create an insert trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want Develop a trigger that will be placed on the marketing list table that will insert a record into the child table if the person’s age is less than 18 once an insert is attempted. The child table and the marketing list table has the same fields. I started this so far. How do I continue?

```
create table child_list
(
Id              int         primary key,
Name            varchar(20)         ,
Date_of_Birth   date                ,
Gender          char(1)             ,
Parish          varchar(20)         ,
Mobile          integer             ,
Mobile_Provider varchar(7)          ,
age             integer, 
age_cat varchar(20)
```

);

```
 create trigger insert_child
   on marketing_list
  for insert 
   as
   if age<18....
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have identity column on child table, following is your query:

```
create table child_list
(
child_list_Id              int         primary key,
Name            varchar(20)         ,
Date_of_Birth   date                ,
Gender          char(1)             ,
Parish          varchar(20)         ,
Mobile          integer             ,
Mobile_Provider varchar(7)          ,
age             integer, 
age_cat varchar(20)
)
go

create table marketing_list
(
marketing_list_Id              int         primary key,
VName            varchar(20)         ,
Date_of_Birth   date                ,
Gender          char(1)             ,
Parish          varchar(20)         ,
Mobile          integer             ,
Mobile_Provider varchar(7)          ,
age             integer, 
age_cat varchar(20)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_InsertChildList
ON marketing_list
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AGE INT
    SET @AGE = (SELECT age FROM INSERTED)

    IF (@AGE < 18)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO child_list 
        SELECT
            marketing_list_Id 
            ,Name
            ,Date_of_Birth
            ,Gender
            ,Parish
            ,Mobile
            ,Mobile_Provider
            ,age
            ,age_cat
        FROM INSERTED
    END
END

INSERT INTO marketing_list VALUES (1,'Test','03-04-1994',1,'Parish','123','AT&T',16,'age_cat')
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SET @AGE = (SELECT age FROM INSERTED)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get *one* arbitrary row, and **ignore** all others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: if your INSERT statements affects 25 rows, trigger executes 25 times. As insert is an row by row operation.

Comment: ***NO!*** If you have a single `INSERT` statement that inserts 25 rows, the trigger will fire ***ONCE*** only - it is ***NOT*** row-by-row!